# resque worker load distribution not fair

Tags: sinatra, redis, resque

I have a Resque Job backed by ActiveRecord that saves a post message to the database.
Have 7 worker instances running. I send 20K records to my sinatra application.
When i query the redis database, i see the following results...

```
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6929:default
"5696"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6930:default
"1"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6942:default
"1"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6953:default
"10854"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6959:default
"3446"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6972:default
"1"
redis> get resque:stat:processed:localhost:6986:default
"1"
```

can anyone comment on it please?
 4 of the 7 workers only processed 1 job each in their lifetime

Comment: on digging further, i realized that the 4 workers took a very long time (more than 10 minutes) to complete their save jobs with AR. In the mean time the other 3 workers completed the rest of the remaining tasks laboriously. I am trying to figure out as to why the 4 workers took soo long to call .save on the AR model.

Comment: Also noticed that there is a big difference in the number of jobs the other 3 workers performed. 10854, 5696 and 3446. One of the guys laboriously did most of the stuff.

Comment: Another finding, when i run the workers for a second run (after all the jobs of the 1st run are done), there is equitable distribution of tasks and all the workers work correctly.
So, looks like during the first run some of the workers were left craving for a connection or they got a connection but just couldnt  use it. But AR should have cried foul (connection timeout or something).
No AR errors for the looong running jobs.

I will try to implement ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out when i replaced ActiveRecord with RDBI. I was getting the following error when my workers were trying to connect to the oracle database

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:281)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:118)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:224)
```

After googling, i stumbled upon this post http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3793101 . So, i decided to pass the -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom option to my jvm. I edited the settings in glassfish's jvm options, but that did not work as those settings benefited my sinatra app but not the resque workers running in the background.

So, i had to start the resque workers by passing the jvm argument. I wrote a rake task to do the same.

```
desc "Start multiple workers for JRUBY production environment which ocnnects to oracle database"
task :start_workers => :setup do

threads = []

ENV['COUNT'].to_i.times do
  threads << Thread.new do
    system "/usr/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djruby.home=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0 -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/bash -Djffi.boot.library.path=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/native/ppc-Linux:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/native/i386-Linux:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/native/x86_64-Linux -Xmx500m -Xss1024k -Djruby.memory.max=500m -Djruby.stack.max=1024k -Dsun.java.command=org.jruby.Main -Djava.class.path=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.6-bin.jar:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar: -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.0/lib/jruby.jar org/jruby/Main /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.0/bin/rake resque:work RACK_ENV=#{ENV['RACK_ENV']} QUEUE=#{ENV['QUEUE']} INTERVAL=#{ENV['INTERVAL']}"
  end
end

threads.each { |thread| thread.join }

end
```